# Event arguments running sequential in html elements

Tags: javascript, html

```
// Send AJAX request to route
function fetch_post(key, ...values){
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let value of values){
        formData.append(key, value)
    }
    fetch('/settings', {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    });
}
```

In this attribute-value:

```
onchange="fetch_post(this.name, this.value); location.reload();"
```

I want `location.reload()` runs when the `fetch_post` running is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want location.reload() runs when the fetch_post running is finished.

`then` is promise chaining.

If fetch is successfully invoked, the code is executed.

```js
    fetch('/settings', {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        location.reload();
    });
```

Comment: Sometimes I should have fetching data, it dont refresh the page. This is for `onchange` specific elements.

Comment: Your problem is that the `location.reload` doesn't work? then try `window.location.reload();`.

Comment: If you use `then`, the page reload is executed when you save it in the database.

Comment: The `location.reload` works. the reload is disturb fetching data to the server.

Comment: What do you mean, you transferred it to 'post' and got the data? Show me the entire code.

Comment: This is flask framework. I have received data in route function. ("/settings")

Answer (score 1):

Just add location.reload() in then function of fetch like this:

```
// Send AJAX request to route
function fetch_post(key, ...values){
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let value of values){
        formData.append(key, value)
    }
    fetch('/settings', {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData
    }).then((data) => {
        location.reload(); <----- this
    }).catch((err)=> {
    }).finally(() => {
    });
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Sometimes I dont want page reload after fetching.

Comment: If you don't call at then of fetch or don't using await, your program will run asynchronous not sequential. While your server take a while to response, your program will reload first

Comment: I need same have a function for `location.reload()` witch runs when `fetch_post` has send data to server. (I need store this in database)

Comment: you put `location.reload();` in `then` of fetch that means you send data to server and then server response success,  `location.reload();` will be run. If you put to `catch` that means you send data to server and then server response fail,  `location.reload();` will be run. And If you put to `finally` that means you send data to server and `location.reload();` always will be run after your server response